# What does "char *p, *getenv();" do? Why a function with no args in a variable declaration line?

Tags: c, function

I'm reading a bit of code in C, and in the variable declaration line, there's `"char *p, *getenv();"`

I understand `"char *p"` of course. What does `"char *getenv()"` do? Later on in the code, the function `getenv()` is called with a variable passed to it. But what's the point of `"char *getenv();"` without any arguments?

Sorry if this is basic. I'm just starting to learn C.

Answer (score 2):

It is "valid C" (I would almost say "unfortunately") - but it is not particularly useful. It is a "declaration without declaration" - "I will be using a function `getenv()` but I'm not going to tell you what the arguments will be". It does have the advantage of preventing a compiler warning / error - something that would normally be prevented with a "real" function prototype, for example by including the appropriate .h file (in this case, `stdlib.h`).

To clarify: the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char *p;
  p = getenv("PATH");
  printf("the path is %s\n", p);
  return 0;
}
```

will throw a compiler warning (and you should never ignore compiler warnings):

```
nonsense.c: In function ‘main’:
nonsense.c:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getenv’
nonsense.c:5: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

Either adding `#include <stdlib.h>` or the line you had above, will make the warning go away (even with `-Wall -pedantic` compiler flags). The compiler will know what to do with the return value - and it figures out the type of the arguments on the fly because it knows the type when it sees it.

And that is the key point: until you tell the compiler the **type of the return value of the function** it does not know what to do (it will assume `int`, and make appropriate conversions for the variable you are assigning to - this can be inappropriate. For example, a pointer is often bigger than an `int`, so information will be lost in the conversion.)

Answer (score 1):

It's a declaration (an old-style one without a prototype, since the argument list is missing) for the function `getenv`. Aside from being arguably bad style to hide a function declaration alongside the declaration of an object like this, it's bad to omit the prototype and bad not to be using the standard headers (`stdlib.h` in this case) to get the declarations of standard functions.